# Can I limit Ghidra's analysis to a particular Program Trees subfolder (block)?

Tags: ghidra

Is there a way to limit Ghidra's analysis to a particular identified subfolder in the Program Trees view?

I'm very new to Ghidra and trying to use it to investigate a large library. I've attempted to run the "sane default" analysis tasks on it, but found that the resulting project was on track to fill up my hard drive if I allowed the analysis to continue.

This binary contains many Ghidra-identified subfolders (memory blocks?) in the Program Trees view, but I'm really only interested in deeply analyzing 1 of them at the moment. I realize that may hinder results as references may point to memory outside of the folder, but I'm willing to accept that tradeoff if it lets me limit the project to a more reasonable size on the disk.

Thanks!